# Return empty recursive mysql if one of items not match with where

Tags: sql, mariadb, recursive-query

I have a recursive query that returns all elements until the parent element but I need it to not return any result if any of the elements has the active = 0.

organigram table:

| idElement | idClient | idSubClient | idSport | idCategory | idTeam | idParent | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | -1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | -1 | 30 | (null) | (null) | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | -1 | (null) | 100 | (null) | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 120 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | -1 | 35 | (null) | (null) | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | -1 | (null) | 125 | (null) | 5 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 130 | 6 | 1 |

organigram_users table:

| idRef | idElement | idUser | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 50 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 50 | 1 |

The reverse query:

```
with recursive elem as (
   select elem.idUser, elem.idElement as root, o.idElement, o.idParent, o.idSport, o.active
   from organigram_users elem
   join organigram o on o.idElement = elem.idElement
   where elem.idUser = 50 and o.idClient = 1 and o.idSubClient = -1
   UNION ALL
   select elem.idUser, elem.root, o.idElement, o.idParent, o.idSport, o.active
   from elem 
   join organigram o on o.idElement = elem.idParent
)
select idElement, idParent, active,idsport, root
from elem          
group by idelement
```

I have an org chart where I can assign a user to more than one item in the org chart. Based on the element where it is assigned I like to check all the parents if the column "active" is 1 or 0. If one of the parnet elements has active = 0 then it doesn't return anything.

In this case the user is assigned to element 4 and 7. The query should show me only the parent elements of element 7 because the parent of element 4 is active = 0

The expected result (because the third element have active = 0):
1
5
6
7

But the result is:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a6b44/1)

I checked my recursive query [here](https://sqliteonline.com/) with MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
with recursive elem as (
   select elem.idUser, elem.idElement as root, o.idElement, o.idParent, o.idSport, o.active
   from organigram_users elem
   join organigram o on o.idElement = elem.idElement
   where elem.idUser = 50 and o.idClient = 1 and o.idSubClient = -1
   UNION ALL
   select elem.idUser, elem.root, o.idElement, o.idParent, o.idSport, o.active
   from elem 
   join organigram o on o.idElement = elem.idParent
), elements
as (
select idElement, idParent, active,idsport, root
from elem          
group by idelement
)
select * from elements
where not exists (select 'x' from elements where active=false)
```

Comment: I change my question. I my case a user it can be assigned to more than one element and I need to get all parents until the element with idPadren is null but only if all parent elements is active = 1

Comment: What you can typically do in a case like this is to add a remembered value for all the rows. So I would pick 2 string values y/n to represent active/non-active and then concatenate them for every recursion. So for the anchor row, if active, y else n as audittrail. For the successive rows(union all part), elem.audittrail + (if active, y else n).

Comment: At the end, each row will have an audit trail of where it came from and all you need to do is filter out where audittrail not like ‘%n%’. What’s a bit confusing here is that you are starting from children and finding parents while recursion usually goes from lower node density to higher. Maybe the children are the parents in this particular situation. In any case, once you start looking at the audit trail of the recursion path, it should give you a few ideas.